# Two identical objects with same methods outputting different results

Tags: javascript

so here's my code as you can see you have an object named 'Obj' then you have 
a class named 'myClass' which creates objects which are as identical as the 'Obj' Object but the run method in the object 'newObj' created from the myClass outputs different results which makes no sense because both objects are 100% the same

```
    var x = 10; //global var
    var Obj =  {
        x:30 ,
        run : () => {
          console.log(this.x);
      }
    }
    console.log(Obj)
    Obj.run() //outputs 10

    //a class which creates the same 'Obj' Object
    class myClass {
      constructor() {
        this.x=30
        this.run = () => {
          console.log(this.x)
        }
      }
    }
    var newObj = new myClass()
    console.log(newObj); //outputs an object which is as identical as the 'Obj' Object
    newObj.run(); //outputs 30 instead of 10
```

that's it 
thanks in advance

Comment: `Obj` is just an object literal, not an instance, and when you declare it the `this` keyword refers to the global context (e.g. `windwow`). That class code you're showing doesn't create the same object in the slightest.

Comment: `this` in `Obj` is `window`. Replace `this.x` with `Obj.x` if you want the property of `Obj`.

Comment: hey , but the console shows they are identical

Comment: also both objects exist in the same scope (the global scope)

Comment: `this` in javascript is confusing, but here using `new` (on a class or on a function (yes you can do that)) creates an object scope (which is accessed by `this`). In the object literal you never call a function so a new scope is never created so you don't get a new `this` scope. Had you used `function` key word instead of an arrow you would have gotten another scope that would be tied to the caller (even more confusing that what you have) But it's an arrow function, the scope is tied to the creation scope of window. `this` refers to the owning scope, not owning object. and scope can change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using an arrow function inside an object, `this` becomes `window`, not the `Obj`. But in the class, the run function is inside the constructor function, making `this` the object, instead of the `window`. If you want the object to print the objects x, then you need to use `Obj.x`.

```
var Obj =  {
    x:30 ,
    run : () => {
      console.log(Obj.x);
  }
}
```

Even if both the objects are in the same scope, they aren't *created* in the same scope, and they aren't created in the same way. Classes are constructors, objects are not.

If you really do want to use the `this` keyword, then instead of `run : () =>`, you can simply replace it with `run ()`.  Then you can use `this.x` instead of `Obj.x`. Its kind of like defining a function in a class (outside its constructor).

```
var Obj =  {
    x:30 ,
    run () {
      console.log(this.x);
  }
}
```

Comment: so arrow functions do not have any effect when used as methods in classes ?

Comment: what i mean by this is that i have used arrow functions in myClass too so "this" should refer to window object aswell ?

Comment: arrow functions can't make constructors. Its `this` keyword is its parent function's `this`. Which in case of the constructor is the constructor, which is the parent function of the arrow function.

Comment: the scope of a function depends on how they are called, as well as how they are created. Arrow functions are immune to that (they are not just a short hand, they change functionality). Arrow functions tend to behave how you are used to them behaving in other languages. (`this` refers to the scope that created the function, not the scope that called the function.)

Comment: since classes are always instantiated with the `new` keyword, you can expect an arrow function inside it to always have `this` refer to the instance of the class. But that is a consequence of how classes are constructed in javascript. It's not exactly a language feature.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in a browser, when you say `var x = 10; // global var` the global object is the browser's `window`, so you are saying `window.x = 10;`

You then create your "Obj" and assign *its* x, `x:30`, but you're still in the global context, so in there when "run" runs, `this` is still referring to `window` and `window.x` is 10.

When you have `myClass` and construct one of them to be `newObj`, at that point `this` now refers to the *constructed object*, so `this.x` refers to the *classes* member `x`, which is 30.

They may look the same when viewed in the console, but that's because the console is working in the same scope both times. Try putting a breakpoint on each of the lines where you do `console.log` and inspect the value of `this` and of `this.x` *when you've hit the breakpoint*.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the run fuction to

```
run() {
  console.log(this.x);
}
```

```js
var x = 10; //global var

var Obj =  {
    x:30 ,
    run() {
      console.log(this.x);
    }
}

console.log(Obj)
Obj.run() //outputs 10

//a class which creates the same 'Obj' Object
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this.x = 30
    this.run = () => {
      console.log(this.x)
    }
  }
}
var newObj = new myClass()
console.log(newObj); //outputs an object which is as identical as the 'Obj' Object
newObj.run(); //outputs 30 instead of 10
```